# Unit testing with mockito and spy causing error

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, mockito, tdd

I am using `Mockito` and Spy to unit test a function.

This is the class under test:

```
public class RecipeListModelImp
        implements RecipeListModelContract {

    private Subscription subscription;
    private RecipesAPI recipesAPI;

    @Inject
    public RecipeListModelImp(@NonNull RecipesAPI recipesAPI) {
        this.recipesAPI = Preconditions.checkNotNull(recipesAPI);
    }

    @Override
    public void getRecipesFromAPI(final RecipeGetAllListener recipeGetAllListener) {
        subscription = recipesAPI.getAllRecipes()
               .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Subscriber<List<Recipe>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {
                              }
                    @Override

                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                                  recipeGetAllListener.onRecipeGetAllFailure(e.getMessage());

                    }


                    @Override

                    public void onNext(List<Recipe> recipe) {                       recipeGetAllListener.onRecipeGetAllSuccess(recipe);
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    public void shutdown() {
        if(subscription != null && !subscription.isUnsubscribed()) {
            subscription.unsubscribe();
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to test using Mockito and spy as I don’t want to call the real function `recipesAPI.getAllRecipes()` just verify it.The test is called `testGetRecipesFromAPI()`

```
public class RecipeListModelImpTest {
    @Mock Subscription subscription;
    @Mock RecipesAPI recipesAPI;
    @Mock RecipeListModelContract.RecipeGetAllListener recipeGetAllListener;

    private RecipeListModelContract recipeListModel;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(RecipeListModelImpTest.this);
        recipeListModel = new RecipeListModelImp(recipesAPI);
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetRecipesFromAPI() {
        RecipeListModelContract recipeListModelSpy = spy(recipeListModel);
        RecipesAPI recipeApiSpy = spy(recipesAPI);
        doNothing().when(recipeApiSpy).getAllRecipes();

        recipeListModelSpy.getRecipesFromAPI(recipeGetAllListener);

        verify(recipesAPI, times(1)).getAllRecipes();

    }

    @Test
    public void testShouldShutdown() {
        recipeListModel.shutdown();
        verify(subscription, times(1)).unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

This is the error:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Only void methods can doNothing()!
Example of correct use of doNothing():
    doNothing().
    doThrow(new RuntimeException())
    .when(mock).someVoidMethod();
Above means:
someVoidMethod() does nothing the 1st time but throws an exception the 2nd time is called
```

I have also tried this which causes a null pointer:

```
  @Test
    public void testGetRecipesFromAPI() {
        RecipeListModelContract recipeListModelSpy = spy(recipeListModel);
        RecipesAPI recipeApiSpy = spy(recipesAPI);

        doReturn(Observable.just(Subscription.class)).when(recipeApiSpy).getAllRecipes();

        recipeListModelSpy.getRecipesFromAPI(recipeGetAllListener);

        verify(recipesAPI, times(1)).getAllRecipes();
    }
```

Comment: at what line do you get NullPointer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in the code is this part: `subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())`. If only we could eliminate this, then we'd be ok returning a test data from `recipesAPI` and test whether this data has been correctly handled by `recipeGetAllListener`.

So, we have to somehow create a seam: if this is a production code - then use `Schedulers.io()`/`AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()`, if this is a test code - then use some particular scheduler.

Let's declare an interface, that will provide `Scheduler`s:

```
    interface SchedulersProvider {
        Scheduler getWorkerScheduler();
        Scheduler getUiScheduler();
    }
```

Now let's make `RecipeListModelImp` have a dependency on `SchedulersProvider`:

```
    public class RecipeListModelImp implements RecipeListModelContract {

        ...
        private SchedulersProvider schedulersProvider;

        @Inject
        public RecipeListModelImp(@NonNull RecipesAPI recipesAPI, 
                                  @NonNull SchedulersProvider schedulerProvider) {
            ...
            this.schedulersProvider = schedulersProvider;
        }

        ...
    }
```

Now, we'll substitute schedulers:

```
    @Override
    public void getRecipesFromAPI(final RecipeGetAllListener recipeGetAllListener) {
        subscription = recipesAPI.getAllRecipes()
                                 .subscribeOn(schedulersProvider.getWorkerScheduler())
                                 .observeOn(schedulersProvider.getUiScheduler())
                                 ...
    }
```

It's time for taking care of providing `SchedulerProvider`:

```
    @Module
    public class MyModule {
        ...
        @Provides public SchedulerProvider provideSchedulerProvider() {
            return new SchedulerProvider() {
                @Override
                Scheduler getWorkerScheduler() {
                    return Schedulers.io();
                }

                @Override
                Scheduler getUiScheduler() {
                    return AndroidSchedulers.mainThread();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Now let's create another module - `TestModule`, which would provide dependencies for test classes. `TestModule` will extend `MyModule` and override the method that provided `SchedulerProvider`:

```
    public class TestModule extends MyModule {
        @Override public SchedulerProvider provideSchedulerProvider() {
            return new SchedulerProvider() {
                @Override
                Scheduler getScheduler() {
                    return Schedulers.trampoline();
                }

                @Override
                Scheduler getUiScheduler() {
                    return Schedulers.trampoline();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

[`Schedulers.trampoline()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/schedulers/Schedulers.html#trampoline()) will execute tasks on current thread.

It's time is to create test component:

```
    @Component(modules = MyModule.class)
    public interface TestComponent extends MyComponent {
        void inject(RecipeListModelImpTest test);
    }
```

Now in the test class:

```
    public class RecipeListModelImpTest {

        @Mock RecipesAPI recipesAPI;
        @Mock RecipeListModelContract.RecipeGetAllListener recipeGetAllListener;

        @Inject SchedulerProvider schedulerProvider;

        private RecipeListModelContract recipeListModel;

        @Before
        public void setup() {
            TestComponent component = DaggerTestComponent.builder()
                                                         .myModule(new TestModule())
                                                         .build();
            component.inject(this);

            MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
            recipeListModel = new RecipeListModelImp(recipesAPI, schedulerProvider);
        }
        ...
    }
```

And the actual testing part:

```
    private static final List<Recipe> TEST_RECIPES = new ArrayList<Recipe>() {
        {
            add(new Recipe(1)),
            add(new Recipe(2))
        }
    };

    @Test
    public void testGetRecipesFromAPI() {
        when(recipeAPI.getAllRecipes())
            .thenReturn(Observable.fromIterable(TEST_RECIPES));

        recipeListModel.getRecipesFromAPI(recipeGetAllListener);

        // verifying, that `recipeAPI.getAllRecipes()` has been called once
        verify(recipeAPI).getAllRecipes();

        // verifying, that we received correct result
        verify(recipeGetAllListener).onRecipeGetAllSuccess(TEST_RECIPES);
    }
```

Comment: that was an excellent answer and solved my problem. That is my preferred way to use mocks and inject using dagger. Just a quick question should be need to extend the base component?. i.e. `public interface TestComponent extends MyComponent`

Comment: Yes, that's because maybe you also have other dependencies that you want to inject. If you do *not* extend the base component, then dagger would fail to provide those depedencies.

Comment: You gave me some great answer. However, i have another problem with testing RxJava2 with espresso where I am trying to mock the data return from the API so I can test in isolation. However, I am getting a null pointer exception on SubscribeOn(..) My questions is located here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45717803/testing-rxjava2-using-espresso-and-getting-a-null-pointer-exception-when-suscrib it would be great if you could provide another expert answer. There is a 500 point reward. Thanks in advance.

Comment: But what if I'm creating a unit test for a bug that occurred specifically for using parallel execution on Schedulers.io() ? If I replace it with trampoline, the unit test will not fail for the buggy code.

Comment: @JustAMartin, you are dealing with non properly synchronized mutable state, which should not be a case for this particular scenario. Can you describe your issue in details?

Comment: @azizbekian  in my case the bug was caused by using flatMapComletable instead of concatMapCompletable.  So, to reproduce the bug, I need to force parallel execution of observables. However, it seems, `trampoline` makes flatMapComletable execute on the same thread. Thus I am not able to create a test case for the bug. But I'll make a new question for the issue.

Answer (score 2):

as you wrote

> subscription = recipesAPI.getAllRecipes().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())

then method getAllRecipes() returns some object , and you can't use

> doNothing().when(recipeApiSpy).getAllRecipes();

doNothing() - it's for method returns void.

variant is correct :

doReturn(doReturn(Observable.just(Subscription.class)).when(recipeApiSpy).getAllRecipes()

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing Spy (partial mocks) and Mocks (full mocks). This is unnecessary - `Spy` allows you to mix mocking and real method calls, but you don't need any partial mocking. In your case you are either full mocking or not mocking. Mockito's [documentation](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.8.9/org/mockito/Mockito.html) has more information on mocking and spying.

In your first example, the error is that you are trying to `doNothing` on a method that returns something. Mockito does not allow that. What you were doing in your second example was almost correct.

For your second example, the issue is you setup `getAllRecipes()` to return the `Observable.just(Subscription.class)` but you still have the entire chain of methods being called on that in the unit under test: `subscribeOn`, `observeOn`, and `subscribe`. You need to mock those calls as well to return mocked objects that you can work with or those calls with throw a NullPointerException.

```
@Test
public void testGetRecipesFromAPI() { 
    //recipesAPI.getAllRecipes() needs to be mocked to return something (likely a mock)
    // so subscribeOn can be called.
    //That needs to be mocked to return something so observeOn can be called
    //etc.

    recipeListModel.getRecipesFromAPI(recipeGetAllListener);

    verify(recipesAPI, times(1)).getAllRecipes();
}
```