# Testing RxJava2 using Espresso and getting a null pointer exception when suscribeOn

Tags: android, unit-testing, nullpointerexception, android-espresso, android-instrumentation

```
Android Studio 3.0 Beta2
```

I am testing getting a list for an endpoint using RxJava2. The app works fine when running normally. However, when I test using espresso I get a null pointer exception when I try and `subscribeOn(scheduler)`. For the schedulers I use the `trampoline()` for both `subscribeOn` and `observeOn` which are injected.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'io.reactivex.Observable io.reactivex.Observable.subscribeOn(io.reactivex.Scheduler)' on a null object reference
```

For testing RxJava2 using espresso is there anything I should do that is different for the `subscribeOn` and `observeOn`?

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {
        MockNetworkModule.class,
        MockAndroidModule.class,
        MockExoPlayerModule.class
})
public interface TestBusbyBakingComponent extends BusbyBakingComponent {
    TestRecipeListComponent add(MockRecipeListModule mockRecipeListModule);
}
```

This is my class under test

```
public class RecipeListModelImp
        implements RecipeListModelContract {

    private RecipesAPI recipesAPI;
    private RecipeSchedulers recipeSchedulers;
    private CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();

    @Inject
    public RecipeListModelImp(@NonNull RecipesAPI recipesAPI, @NonNull RecipeSchedulers recipeSchedulers) {
        this.recipesAPI = Preconditions.checkNotNull(recipesAPI);
        this.recipeSchedulers = Preconditions.checkNotNull(recipeSchedulers);
    }

    @Override
    public void getRecipesFromAPI(final RecipeGetAllListener recipeGetAllListener) {
        compositeDisposable.add(recipesAPI.getAllRecipes()
                .subscribeOn(recipeSchedulers.getBackgroundScheduler()) /* NULLPOINTER EXCEPTION HERE */
                .observeOn(recipeSchedulers.getUIScheduler())
                .subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<List<Recipe>>() {
                    @Override
                    protected void onStart() {}

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(@io.reactivex.annotations.NonNull List<Recipe> recipeList) {
                        recipeGetAllListener.onRecipeGetAllSuccess(recipeList);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        recipeGetAllListener.onRecipeGetAllFailure(e.getMessage());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {}
                }));
    }

    @Override
    public void releaseResources() {
        if(compositeDisposable != null && !compositeDisposable.isDisposed()) {
            compositeDisposable.clear();
            compositeDisposable.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

The interface for the schedulers is here and for testing I am using trampoline which is injected

```
@Module
public class MockAndroidModule {
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    Context providesContext() {
        return Mockito.mock(Context.class);
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    Resources providesResources() {
        return Mockito.mock(Resources.class);
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    SharedPreferences providesSharedPreferences() {
        return Mockito.mock(SharedPreferences.class);
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    RecipeSchedulers provideRecipeSchedulers() {
        return new RecipeSchedulers() {
            @Override
            public Scheduler getBackgroundScheduler() {
                return Schedulers.trampoline();
            }

            @Override
            public Scheduler getUIScheduler() {
                return Schedulers.trampoline();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Mock Module for RecipleAPI

```
@Module
public class MockNetworkModule {
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    public RecipesAPI providesRecipeAPI() {
        return Mockito.mock(RecipesAPI.class);
    }
}
```

This is how the components are created

```
public class TestBusbyBakingApplication extends BusbyBakingApplication {
    private TestBusbyBakingComponent testBusbyBakingComponent;
    private TestRecipeListComponent testRecipeListComponent;

    @Override
    public TestBusbyBakingComponent createApplicationComponent() {
        testBusbyBakingComponent = createTestBusbyBakingComponent();
        testRecipeListComponent = createTestRecipeListComponent();

        return testBusbyBakingComponent;
    }

    private TestBusbyBakingComponent createTestBusbyBakingComponent() {
        testBusbyBakingComponent = DaggerTestBusbyBakingComponent.builder()
                .build();

        return testBusbyBakingComponent;
    }

    private TestRecipeListComponent createTestRecipeListComponent() {
        testRecipeListComponent = testBusbyBakingComponent.add(new MockRecipeListModule());
        return testRecipeListComponent;
    }
}
```

And for the expresso test I am doing the following:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class RecipeListViewAndroidTest {
    @Inject RecipesAPI recipesAPI;

    @Mock RecipeListModelContract.RecipeGetAllListener mockRecipeListener;

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mainActivity =
            new ActivityTestRule<>(
                    MainActivity.class,
                    true,
                    false);

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        Instrumentation instrumentation = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation();
        BusbyBakingApplication busbyBakingApplication =
                (BusbyBakingApplication)instrumentation.getTargetContext().getApplicationContext();

        TestBusbyBakingComponent component = (TestBusbyBakingComponent)busbyBakingApplication.createApplicationComponent();
        component.add(new MockRecipeListModule()).inject(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnAListOfRecipes() throws Exception {
        List<Recipe> recipeList = new ArrayList<>();
        Recipe recipe = new Recipe();
        recipe.setName("Test Brownies");
        recipe.setServings(10);
        recipeList.add(recipe);

        when(recipesAPI.getAllRecipes()).thenReturn(Observable.just(recipeList));
        doNothing().when(mockRecipeListener).onRecipeGetAllSuccess(recipeList);

        mainActivity.launchActivity(new Intent());

        onView(withId(R.id.rvRecipeList)).check(matches(hasDescendant(withText("Test Brownies"))));
    }
}
```

Stack trace:

```
at me.androidbox.busbybaking.recipieslist.RecipeListModelImp.getRecipesFromAPI(RecipeListModelImp.java:37)
at me.androidbox.busbybaking.recipieslist.RecipeListPresenterImp.retrieveAllRecipes(RecipeListPresenterImp.java:32)
at me.androidbox.busbybaking.recipieslist.RecipeListView.getAllRecipes(RecipeListView.java:99)
at me.androidbox.busbybaking.recipieslist.RecipeListView.onCreateView(RecipeListView.java:80)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2192)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1299)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:758)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2363)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2149)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2103)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2013)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:388)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:607)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:178)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1237)
at android.support.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.callActivityOnStart(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:544)
at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6268)
```

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: Can you post the stack trace of the exception you are getting? Also, where is MockRecipeSchedulersModule getting injected?  I only see MockRecipeListModule being injected.

Comment: @jdonmoyer Sorry I included the wrong module. Its is called MockAndroidModule which contains the providers that returns the schedulers (I have updated my question). The way they are getting injected is using constructor injection. Inject
    public RecipeListModelImp(NonNull RecipesAPI recipesAPI, NonNull RecipeSchedulers recipeSchedulers). I can't provide a stack trace until I get home later today. Thanks

Comment: Where do you provide test implementation of RecipesAPI? I can only see, that it is injected in RecipeListViewAndroidTest and is of `Mock` type right? Furthermore I don't see, where `MockAndroidModule` is added to `TestBusbyBakingComponent`. Could you please elaborate on this more?

Comment: @R.Zagórski I have updated my question. Yes, the RecipeAPI will return the mock interface basically mock(RecipeAPI.class). I have added this. I have added the TestBusbyBakingComponent to my question. However, I feel the problem is related to the Schedulers that is passed into the SubscribeOn(...)

Comment: Please post `RecipeListModelImp`.

Comment: @azizbekian it's already posted. It's the first code snippet.

Comment: Please also share `TestBusbyBakingComponent`.

Comment: Added it as the first snippet. Actually the project is in my github: checkout the develop branch: https://github.com/steve1rm/BusbyBaking/tree/develop

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are numerous of problems in your codebase. But first and foremost is following: you are somehow instantiating new real objects (not mocks) and that's why you are getting NPE, there is nothing to do with `subscribeOn()`.

1. You should make your test component extend from your production component. Currently it is **not**.

   ```
   public interface TestRecipeListComponent extends RecipeListComponent {...}
   ```
2. In your test application class you are mixing callbacks, i.e. you are creating `TestRecipeListComponent` within `createApplicationComponent` callback, but you have another callback for doing that: `createRecipeListComponent()`.
3. You should **not** mock out each an everything in your `MockRecipeListModule`. Just mock out component, that you really need to mock out. For example, if you mock `RecipeAdapter`, then how come you expect recycler view to draw anything on the screen? You just need to mock out data source provider, which in your case is `RecipeApi`. Other than that nothing should be mocked out, this is not a unit test, this is instrumentation test.
4. Within `RecipeListView#onCreate()` you are creating a new `RecipeListComponent`, whereas you should **not**, you should get that component from the `Application` class, because you have already created it there. This affect on the tests: you cannot control dependencies from there, because `RecipeListView` would just ignore all the dependencies you have changed from tests and will create a new component which will provide other dependencies, thus your stubs would **not** return the data that you have explicitly hard coded in test (in fact they won't be even called, real objects would be). This is exactly what you were experiencing the issue from.

I've fixed all of this. I've come to a point where the assertion you wrote does not pass. You should take the hassle to continue with this, because it is connected with the logics/architecture you are using.

I've opened a pull request [here](https://github.com/steve1rm/BusbyBaking/pull/27/files).

Comment: Great work. I have checked the code and everything worked ok. I had to make some minor refactoring in TestBusbyBakingApplication and I have created a PR here: https://github.com/azizbekian/BusbyBaking/pull/1. However, this answered my question. Great thanks.